# Weakly retaining container class

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C is there a container class that will weakly retain the objects in it. I know that NSArray and NSSet will retain the objects in them strongly. But is there something that will allow them to become deallocated (and update accordingly) when they are no longer used by anyone else?
Are there any mutable versions of this? I need this to keep track of some objects but I don't want to retain them.

Comment: If you are using Xcode 5 unused variables will be deallocated automatically. You don't need to deallocate it by yourself.

Comment: 1. That has nothing to do with Xcode, which is an IDE, not a programming language nor an memory management model. 2. It wouldn't be deallocated, because the array still holds a (strong) reference to the contained object.

Answer (score 4):

[`NSPointerArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSPointerArray_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPointerArray/initWithOptions%3a) et al. do the job, you want.

```
NSPointerArray *pointerArray = [[NSPointerArray alloc] initWithOptions: NSPointerFunctionsWeakMemory];
```

Comment: will this work for storing an array of objective-c code blocks? And is it available on iOs? Or only on the MAC?

Comment: NSPointerArray with NSPointerFunctionsWeakMemory is available since iOS 6 and OS X 10.8.

Comment: @user1028028 1. I have never tried it, but on a first sight I cannot recognize, whether it should not work with blocks. 2. Why don't you use your documentation?

Comment: @Martin R: NSPointerFunctionsObjectPointerPersonality would do a similar job on 10.5 - 10.7. Of course, as usual with MRC, there can be additional work to prevent dangling pointers.

Comment: Hmm... I would like it to automatically remove nil pointers. So if I query it while running I will always have the number of objects in it that where not deallocated.

Comment: You can detect a removal in the relinquish function and remove the object manually.